# What DNS servers am I using?

Tags: networking, dns

How can I check which DNS server am I using (in Linux)? I am using network manager and a wired connection to my university's LAN. (I am trying to find out why my domain doesn't get resolved)

Comment: The Linux kernel itself is not aware about DNS services. To answer it's better to know your userland. What distribution are you using? Ubuntu? Debian GNU/Linux? Centos?

Answer (score 316, accepted):

You should be able to get some reasonable information in:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: However, please be aware that (on modern Linuxen) the contents of `/etc/nsswitch.conf` dictate what name services are used (DNS, LDAP, etc) and in what order. Say `fgrep hosts: /etc/nsswitch.conf`. If it only references DNS, `/etc/resolv.conf` is the right place to look for your nameservers. But chances are you're also using mDNS (aka ZeroConf, aka Avahi, aka Bonjour, etc), etc. In that case, things depend on what you're using.

Comment: This file typically points at 127.0.1.1 on Ubuntu - it's the local DNS cache server, not the actual upstream.

Comment: @BarryKelly Check what your router uses, then

Comment: And if you have several upstream server configured ? How to know which one is currently used ?

Comment: I would suggest to mention that file is a link and dynamically generated for systems using resovconf (like Ubuntu). I've seen this answer millions of times and until today is that I think it is correct, because I understand now that it is actually a dynamically generated file.

Comment: See the answers by @G32RW or @Lonniebiz for a more robust approach under various circumstances, e.g. when you get an answer like `127.0.0.53`

Comment: @Geremia router? I'm on office wifi and I want to verify which DNS server I'm using. Or I'm on VPN and want to verify, similarly. Usually I don't have access to the router.

Comment: This solution is no more up to date. I find the `systemd-resolve --status` suggested by @G32RW most up-to-date solution for this problem.

Comment: There is no "systemd-resolve" in my Ubuntu 22.04 .  Also "nmcli device show | grep -i dns" returns nothing.  However, "resolvectl --protocol=dns | grep 'DNS Servers'" seems to work.

Comment: I would suggest adding: `cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` to your answer if you are running a caching resolver on 127.X.X.X and actually want to know what's behind the cache. Or, as others have answered, you can also run `resolvectl`, or just `resolvectl dns`

Answer (score 305):

Here's how I do it:

```
( nmcli dev list || nmcli dev show ) 2>/dev/null | grep DNS
```

This [worked previous](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617067/why-nm-tool-is-no-longer-available-in-ubuntu-15-04) to the way above:

```
nm-tool | grep DNS
```

On Debian, you need to have the **network-manager package** installed.

Comment: This one is usefull if you are using **VPN** and **NetworkManager**. Your `/etc/resolv.conf` will point to your machine, with `dnsmasq` resolving names as configured by **NetworkManager**.

Comment: On Debian this requires the `network-manager` package.

Comment: nm-tool is not available in newer linuxes. for example it is not in the 'network-manager' package of debian 8.

Comment: `nm-tool | grep DNS
No command 'nm-tool' found, did you mean:
 Command 'dm-tool' from package 'lightdm' (main)
nm-tool: command not found`

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect what's working for me in 2016.

Comment: This did not work for me on an Ubuntu VM. `nmcli dev show` did not have the DNS info. However, `systemd-resolve --status` did have the real DNS server. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434756

Comment: @wisbucky : That didn't work for me in 16.04, but people say its the new way in 18.04+.

Comment: To add, you can also supply an interface name, e.g., `nmcli dev show eth1` to show information about a specific adapter. Useful if you're troubleshooting a specific adapter that's connected differently than others.

Comment: nmcli is only installed for GUI distros, through network-manager package, not evailable in Ubuntu Server by default, for example

Comment: +1 for `systemd-resolve --status` as per https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434756/36362 (as @wisbucky mentions above) on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: What if I'm not using network manager?

Comment: The question specifically indicates the use of Network Manager. If you're not using network manager, see other answers.

Answer (score 177):

On systems running systemd use:

```
systemd-resolve --status
```

Or:

```
resolvectl
```

Comment: systemd-resolve: unrecognized option '--status'

Comment: @A-B-B system? systemd version?

Comment: 229-4ubuntu21.2

Comment: Says `Failed to get global data: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found.`

Comment: This is the new default way to do it in Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver - get used to it, everybody!

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, as the others returned 127.0.0.53

Comment: Not working on OpenSUSE Leap 15.1

Comment: What am I reading? I only see DNSSEC records.

Comment: Since the commands gives a lot of unrelated information, piping the output into `grep DNS` should return only DNS related information, including DNS servers currently in use.

Comment: It says my DNS is 127.0.0.1, which is only the first entry in /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: resolvectl is pretty verbose for me.  `resolvectl dns` seems to give a nice, relatively compact list of DNS server IPs.

Comment: resolvctl worked for me in Ubuntu 22.04 .  nmcli and systemd-resolve solutions did not work.

Answer (score 111):

I think you can also query DNS and it will show you what server returned the result. Try this:

```
dig yourserver.somedomain.xyz
```

And the response should tell you what server(s) returned the result. The output you're interested in will look something like this:

```
;; Query time: 91 msec
;; SERVER: 172.xxx.xxx.xxx#53(172.xxx.xxx.xxx)
;; WHEN: Tue Apr 02 09:03:41 EDT 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 207
```

You can also tell `dig` to query a specific DNS server by using `dig @server_ip`

Comment: On Debian this requires the `dnsutils` package.

Comment: If you use any DNS masking/caching service that is run on your local machine, it will hide the real DNS servers.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 just shows the local dns cache: `SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)`

Comment: This only tells you which server was used for that query.  It doesn't tell you all the DNS servers that your host might use.

Comment: You can find all DNS servers used to satisfy a query by running `dig +trace your.domain`

Comment: Beware that this obviously fails if the DNS server is not available. That's not a common thing, but I've managed to get a bad result or timeout when looking for a DNS server running on IPv6 (using `dig -6`).

Answer (score 85):

Just do an, [`nslookup`](http://man.cx/nslookup%281%29). Part of its results include the server that it's using.

In the example below, it shows that the DNS server used is at 8.8.8.8.

```
$ nslookup google.com
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.22.174
```

Comment: On Debian this requires the `dnsutils` package.

Comment: On a recent Ubuntu, this again points to the local cache server 127.0.0.1 as already hinted at in [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28941/what-dns-servers-am-i-using#comment465023_28944)

Comment: In CentOS 7 it quits with error, but it is a vm so I did `nslookup google.com` in the Windows host and I found the nameserver. Add it in `/etc/resolv.conf` like: `nameserver xx.xx.xx.xx` and restart service `network`, and all is fine. Praise you.

Comment: Note that Nslookup is deprecated

Comment: Didn't work: Server:  127.0.0.53, Address: 127.0.0.53#53

Answer (score 26):

With the new `network-manager` command `nmcli`, do this:

```
nmcli --fields ipv4.dns,ipv6.dns con show [connection_name]
```

On newer versions of network-manager (such as in Ubuntu 16.04), the field names are slightly different:

```
nmcli --fields ip4.dns,ip6.dns con show [connection_name]
```

If you don't know the connection name, use:

```
nmcli -t --fields NAME con show --active
```

For example, on old versions of nmcli :

```
$ nmcli --fields ip4.dns,ip6.dns con show 'Wired connection 1'
IP4.DNS[1]:                             172.21.0.13
IP4.DNS[2]:                             172.21.0.4
```

Comment: My results: `order «con» «show» is not valid`.

Comment: It works fine for me with network-manager 1.0.4 on Ubuntu 15.10. Maybe you have an older version?

Comment: The tabular format is pretty bad. I hope to get a column like format similar to Powershell.

Comment: Returns `Error: invalid field 'ip4.dns'; allowed fields: NAME,UUID,TYPE,TIMESTAMP,TIMESTAMP-REAL,AUTOCONNECT,AUTOCONNECT-PRIORITY,READONLY,DBUS-PATH,ACTIVE,DEVICE,STATE,ACTIVE-PATH.`

Comment: simply `nmcli` was all i needed on ubuntu 19.04

Comment: @FriendFX In newer versions of `nmcli`, the command is :
`nmcli --fields ip4.dns,ip6.dns dev show`

Comment: Ugh, as long as `nmcli` doesn't keep backwards compatibility with specific parameters and output format, I guess this is not a good way of testing for anything.

Answer (score 14):

to get the first DNS SERVER (IP only) :

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf|grep -im 1 '^nameserver' |cut -d ' ' -f2
```

- `cat` will output DNS config
- `grep` filters only nameserver
- `-i` grep ignore case
- `-m 1` grep stop after first match
- `cut` take the ip part of the row (second column with ' ' as separator)

To put DNS ip in an environment variable, you could use as follow:

```
export THEDNSSERVER=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf|grep -im 1 '^nameserver' |cut -d ' ' -f2)
```

Comment: `grep -m 1` stops matching after first match so you don't have to use `head`

Comment: To lighten the pipeline even more, capture groups with Perl regexp is very neat, and grep takes a file argument: `grep -Pom 1 '^nameserver \K\S+' /etc/resolv.conf`. Just wrote up [Capture groups with grep perl regular expression](https://blog.stigok.com/post/capture-groups-with-grep-perl-regular-expression)

Comment: There's both IPv4 and IPv6 DNS servers. Also, secondary servers exist for a reason. Which one this command returns? Is it advised to take the first one, and just ignore the others?

Answer (score 13):

#### Using [`resolvectl`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/systemd/resolvectl.1.en.html)

```
$ resolvectl status | grep -1 'DNS Server'
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: 1.1.1.1
         DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1
                      1.0.0.1
```

> `grep` option: `-C NUM`, `-NUM`, `--context=NUM` Print NUM lines of output context.

For compatibility, `systemd-resolve` is a symbolic link to `resolvectl` on many distros as for Ubuntu 18.10:

```
$ type -a systemd-resolve
systemd-resolve is /usr/bin/systemd-resolve

$ ll /usr/bin/systemd-resolve
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 nov.  15 21:42 /usr/bin/systemd-resolve -> resolvectl

$ type -a resolvectl
resolvectl is /usr/bin/resolvectl

$ file /usr/bin/resolvectl
/usr/bin/resolvectl: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=09e488e849e3b988dd2ac93b024bbba18bb71814, stripped
```

Comment: works perfect on Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: see also https://askubuntu.com/q/1149364/157358 about the name of the program

Comment: As with other answers, thiis will simply return the caching service on your local host.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using network manager probably you get all network parameters from your dhcp server at your university.

If you don't want use your shell to check your dns settings (as described by hesse and Alexios), you can see them from the panel "Network information".

You can reach this panel by pressing right mouse button on network manager icon and selecting "Connection Information" from the menu.

Answer (score 6):

I have Fedora 25 and also had similar slow response on command line to sudo commands.

```
nmcli dev show | grep DNS
```

showed that only one of my 3 adapters (two active) had DNS entries.
By adding DNS entries to the one active card that didn't have an entry - presto!
All is good and response time is immediate.

Comment: perhaps alternatively

Answer (score 4):

### In Ubuntu >= 15

```
nmcli device show <interfacename> | grep IP4.DNS
```

Replace `<interfacename>` with yours.

### In Ubuntu <= 14

The command

```
 nmcli dev list iface <interfacename> | grep IP4
```

Replace `<interfacename>` with yours.

### Examples

```
 nmcli device show eth0 | grep IP4.DNS
```

Or

```
 nmcli dev list iface eth0 | grep IP4
```

This will list all DNS servers(If you use more than one).

Answer (score 3):

On a recent Fedora 33, you can just use

```
# resolvectl dns
Global:
Link 2 (enp0s31f6):
Link 3 (wlp4s0): 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8
Link 4 (virbr0):
Link 5 (virbr0-nic):
```

To check if `systemd-resolved` is active, do `cat /etc/resolv.conf` It will tell you who is controlling the file.

If you want more details, you can use `resolvectl status` `resolvectl statistics`, you can also flush caches ...

To troubleshoot, you can use `journalctl -u systemd-resolved -f  -o cat | grep Looking`  after setting the level to DEBUG: `sudo resolvectl log-level debug`

Comment: Only returns local caching DNS, i.e. localhost.

Answer (score 1):

On systems where `systemd-resolved` is NOT installed :

```bash
$ host -v something.unknown | awk -F "[ #]" '/Received /{print$5}' | uniq
192.168.1.1
```

On systems where `NetworkManager` is running :

```
$ ( nmcli -f IP4.DNS,IP6.DNS dev list || nmcli -f IP4.DNS,IP6.DNS dev show ) 2>/dev/null | awk '/DNS/{print$NF}'
192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS, you can use:

```
/usr/sbin/named -v
```