How to check if I am using protonvpn's dns servers
Question
I would like to check if my system is using proton's DNS servers or not, how can I do this?
Motivation
I'm using safing's portmaster and protonvpn on my device.
By default the portmaster changes the system dns provider to one of the options on it's list, as proton has their own dns provider I'd rather use that instead. From what I can see here https://docs.safing.io/portmaster/guides/dns-configuration (see the disabling dns section at the bottom of the page ) this can be done by simply deleting the dns servers in the portmaster GUI. However, it is not clear to me if this will cause the dns provider to fall back to proton ( as desired ) or if it'll fall back on some default my OS has. Therefore, I'd like to check.
P.S.
if anyone knows of a better way to make the postmaster use proton's dns servers please let me know. Thanks,

I would suggest adding OS info. If it's linux, are you looking for something like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28941/what-dns-servers-am-i-using ?

@Anutrix Should have said in the question but I used the systemd-resolve --status  given in that answer already. It's showing Global Link 2, Link 40 and Link 41 I assume link 40 is the dns server I'm connected to as it's the only one showing info on DNS. However, this only gives me the dns server IP address not who owns it.

I usually just use nslookup for this.

The dig command will tell you which server it's using.
